# Drawing on canvas combined with GestureDetector

Tags: flutter

I want to draw & update a circle on user touch move.. So I found something really similar to what I want here ([Flutter - Creating a custom control with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515611/flutter-creating-a-custom-control-with-flutter))

Here is the copy paste code (just copy paste this in main.dart and you can see the output) of accepted answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new TouchTest());
}

class TouchTest extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Touch Test',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: new Container(

          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: new Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: new Center(
            child: new TouchControl()
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class TouchControl extends StatefulWidget {
  final double xPos;
  final double yPos;
  final ValueChanged<Offset> onChanged;

  const TouchControl({Key key,
    this.onChanged,
    this.xPos:0.0,
    this.yPos:0.0}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TouchControlState createState() => new TouchControlState();
}

/**
 * Draws a circle at supplied position.
 *
 */
class TouchControlState extends State<TouchControl> {
  double xPos = 0.0;
  double yPos = 0.0;

  GlobalKey _painterKey = new GlobalKey();

  void onChanged(Offset offset) {
    final RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
    Offset position = referenceBox.globalToLocal(offset);
    if (widget.onChanged != null)
      widget.onChanged(position);

    setState(() {
      xPos = position.dx;
      yPos = position.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  bool hitTestSelf(Offset position) => true;

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, BoxHitTestEntry entry) {
    if (event is PointerDownEvent ) {
      // ??
    }
  }

  void _handlePanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    onChanged(details.globalPosition);
  }

  void _handlePanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    print('end');
    // TODO
  }

  void _handlePanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    onChanged(details.globalPosition);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
      child: new GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onPanStart:_handlePanStart,
        onPanEnd: _handlePanEnd,
        onPanUpdate: _handlePanUpdate,
        child: new CustomPaint(
          size: new Size(xPos, yPos),
          painter: new TouchControlPainter(xPos, yPos),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TouchControlPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static const markerRadius = 10.0;
  final double xPos;
  final double yPos;

  TouchControlPainter(this.xPos, this.yPos);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue[400]
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(new Offset(xPos, yPos), markerRadius, paint);
  }


  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TouchControlPainter old) => xPos != old.xPos && yPos !=old.yPos;
}
```

The problem is that this runs really slow, nowhere close to 60fps on iOS and on android it's a bit better but still not 60fps.

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: most likely your `TouchControlPainter` is created too often

Comment: basically create one instance of `TouchControlPainter` and repaint it when necessary

Comment: @pskink hey thanks for helping! I understood that `shouldRepaint` does that? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: see [CustomPainterDemo](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/custom_painter_demo.dart) and pay attantion at `super(repaint: notifier)`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Did you understand the problem / find a solution in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

I've run the code locally and the iOS app seems to run at an acceptable frame rate (30fps) where the blue circle is rendered. The delay might have been caused by the rate where the canvas is redrawn on `setState()`. Though I do agree that the frame rate seems to be better on Android by 3~4 frames per second.

**iOS demo**

[image: iOS demo]

**Android demo**

[image: Android demo]

I suggest updating your Flutter version and see if it runs better now compared to its previous performance. Here's my current setup.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.5 20G71 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (9 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1
```